# How can I get distcp failed files and replay the task?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I have distcp a file between two hdfs cluster with same version,when I execute failed ,I want to find the failed mapreduce task and related file path,then replay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying 'retrying' actually [already happens exactly](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp.html#uo) (`mapred.map.max.attempts` times).

If you rerun distcp again, it will only try to copy files that haven't already been copied. (files successfully copied by a previous distcp on a re-execution will be marked as "skipped".)

If you would like a log of the files that couldn't be copied you can specify '`-i`' and `-log <logdir>`.  This will ignore failures but write out a more complete log of what failed and why they failed.